# python regular expression $[a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ]* with forbidding

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for regular expression in Python, that in string finds me:

```
$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*
```

there can be more of this and they can be seperated by whitespaces (\s)

This all would be quite easy, but I also need to forbid the whole string if there is anything that did not match the pattern. (+ empty string is also ok)

I'll give you some examples:

```
$x$y0123 => OK, gives me [$x, $y0123]
$ => BAD (only $)
"" or "  \t" => OK, gives me []    
$x      @hi => BAD, cause @hi, does not match the pattern
```

It can be more regular expressions, it doesn't have to be just one.

`regex = re.compile("(\$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*)") regex.findall(string)`

This would be ok, if i don't have to check those things also.

Comment: There are multiple substrings that might match the pattern? And All of the substrings have to match the pattern. And you want to *get* the individual substrings that match the pattern?

Comment: yeah, I want individual substrings. And I will always check one string at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but maybe you need 2 regex: the first to check the validity of the format, and the second to retrieve the matches.

```
import re
stuff = ["$x$y0123", "$", "", "  \t", "$x      @hi"]

p1 = re.compile(r'(?:\$[A-Z_]\w*|\s)*$', re.IGNORECASE)
p2 = re.compile(r'\$[A-Z_]\w*|\s+', re.IGNORECASE)

for thing in stuff:
    if p1.match(thing):
        print(p2.findall(thing))
```

Will print:

```
['$x', '$y0123']
[]
['  \t']
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/9Kms4t)

Answer (score 0):

To check a whole string you better use re.match function instead of re.findall and pattern that also allows spases will be like this `^((\$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_])|(\s))*$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
s1 = '$x$y0123 $_xyz1$B0dR_'
s2 = '$x$y0123 $_xyz1$B0dR_ @1'
s3 = '$'
s4 = '   \t'
s5 = ''

def process(s, pattern):
    '''Find substrings in s that match pattern

    if string is not completely composed of substings that match pattern
    raises AttributeError

    s --> str
    pattern --> str
    returns list
    '''
    rex = re.compile(pattern)
    matches = list()
    while s:
##        print '*'*8
##        print s1
        m = rex.match(s)
        matches.append(m)
##        print '\t', m.group(), m.span(), m.endpos    
        s = s[m.end():]
    return matches

pattern = '\$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*'
for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]:
    print '*'*8
    # remove whitespace
    s = re.sub('\s', '', s)
    if not s:
        print 'empty string'
        continue
    try:
        matches = process(s, pattern)
    except AttributeError:
        print 'this string has bad stuff in it'
        print s
        continue
    print '\n'.join(m.group() for m in matches)

>>> 
********
$x
$y0123
$_xyz1
$B0dR_
********
this string has bad stuff in it
$x$y0123$_xyz1$B0dR_@1
********
this string has bad stuff in it
$
********
empty string
********
empty string
>>>
```